# Optional Java operand like Ruby's |*foo| for step defiitions

Tags: java, ruby, cucumber

I can't find an answer to this anywhere. Even the question is hard to phrase, so let me ask with code:

In Ruby we can do this (step definition written for Cucumber):

```
When (/foo/) do |*table|
```

The "splat" means that it is optional to get a table.

How can we do this in Java? Other than overloading a method:

```
@When ("foo")    
public void overloadedMethod(){ code }
public void overloadedMethod(table){ code }
```

Is overloading a method the only way to achieve the same result?

Comment: From now on use the word `splat`.  The splat operator is used to handle methods which have a variable parameter list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ruby the asterisk syntax (`*table`) doesn’t just mean that the parameter is optional, but that any parameters are collected together in an array that you can access in the method (or block in this case) body. That could include zero parameters which would give you an empty array.

Java has a similar feature with [varargs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/varargs.html):

```
public void myMethod(AType... things) {
  // things is an array of AType objects
}
```

You can then call this method in any of the following ways (assuming `foo`, `bar` and `baz` are all references to objects of type `AType`:

```
myMethod(foo);

myMethod(foo, bar, baz);

myMethod();
```